# How does power iteration works in Randomized SVD?

Tags: matrix, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, svd

I am studying randomized SVD and reading some articles like https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/01/17/randomized-svd/

https://research.fb.com/blog/2014/09/fast-randomized-svd/

However, I got some questions.

1. In power iteration equation, I cannot understand why Q which is the output of QR decomposition of X is the same as Q which is the output of QR decomposition of (XX^T)^qX. What makes it as same?

===================

A1) I just found that Q of X is not equal to Q of (X*X^T)^q*X

2. It multiplies omega matrix (which is random matrix) to X to downsize matrix X for saving time in getting Q. But how can I assure this Q has almost same range of X?? Is it because X times omega almost catch the action of X? What is the relationship between action of X and range of X?

Sorry for lack of my mathematics skills. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got answers from stack exchange mathematics.
1. At first, Range(X) is equal to Range(XXTX). Therefore, power iteration doesn't affect Range(X). By power iteration, we can extract relevant information related to dominant singular values than naive version.
2. Omega matrix is random sampled, so projection catches dominant action of matrix X. So it can be seen as range of matrix.